# Integral calculation with infinite series

Tags: calculus

so basically i was confronted by the following series:

$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^i}{2(2i+1)(i+1)}$

I encountered this series while working on the following integral:

$\int_0^\infty \frac{(1-cosx)}{(x^2e^x)} dx $

I first expanded the taylor series of $cos(x)$ , and then the integral just came out as a sum of gamma functions. Then I evaluated each of them to end up with the previously mentioned infinite series.
Now according to this video:-https://youtu.be/DVFf-qT3swY?si=aCEeAKot6aZElyv1

This integral equals $ \frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{log2}{2} $, so our sum is equal to
$ \frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{log2}{2} $.

Is my evaluation right? And if someone has better ways to evaluate it I would highly appreciate if its is shared with me.

Comment: The Frullani integral is valid in some cases for a complex number: 
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x(1+i\alpha)}-e^{-x(1+i\beta)}}xdx=\ln\frac{1+i\beta}{1+i\alpha}$$
Using it, for $\alpha\geqslant0$, integrating by parts
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{1-\cos\alpha x}{x^2}e^{-x}dx=\frac12\int_0^\infty\left((1+i\alpha)e^{-x(1+i\alpha)}-e^{-x}+(1-i\alpha)e^{-x(1-i\alpha)}-e^{-x}\right)\frac{dx}x$$
$$=\Re\ln\frac1{1+i\alpha}+\frac{i\alpha}2\ln\frac{1-i\alpha}{1+i\alpha}=-\,\frac{\ln(1+\alpha^2)}2+\alpha\arctan\alpha$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can derive a closed expression for the series as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)(2n+1)}}&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\int_{0}^{1}\left(x^{2n}-x^{2n+1}\right)\,dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left(x^{2n}-x^{2n+1}\right)\,dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx-\int_{0}^1\frac{x}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^1\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\log\left(1+x^2\right)\Big|_{0}^1\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\log(2)}
\end{align*}
according to the claim.